# Flash Messages aren't appearing on page

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-bootstrap

I'm creating a currency converter using python and flask, and trying to flash error messages for invalid inputs. The form automatically routes to the error checks upon submission. I have been manipulating the inputs to purposely raise errors and a KeyError is showing in my browser, but not flashing on my page.

These are the checks I'm trying to do:

```
def check_valid_code():
    converting_from = (request.form['converting_from']).upper()
    converting_to = (request.form['converting_to']).upper()
    c= CurrencyCodes()
    try:
         c.get_symbol(converting_from)
    except KeyError:
        flash("{converting_from} is not a valid currency code!")
    
    try:
         c.get_symbol(converting_to)
    except KeyError:
        flash("{converting_to} is not a valid currency code!")

def check_valid_number():
    amount = request.form['amount']
    if amount.isnumeric() == True:
        amount= float(amount)
        return amount
    else:
        flash("Not a valid amount.")
```

My base.html (using Bootstrap) where the messages should appear:

```
<body>
  <div class="container" style="min-height:100% width:80%">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      {% with errors = get_flashed_messages(category_filter=["danger"]) %}
          {% if errors %}
              {%- for message in errors %}
                  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                      <span>{{ message }}</span>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                  </div>
              {% endfor -%}
          {% endif %}
      {% endwith %}
  </div>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: _a KeyError is showing in my browser_ Show us the entire error mesasge.

Comment: Ex: I enter an invalid input for converting_from, it displays:
"werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'converting_from'"

Comment: Your code is crashing before it even gets to the flash messages.

Comment: What's the `-` for in `{%-`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use render_template library from Flask and your code looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

def check_valid_code():
    converting_from = (request.form['converting_from']).upper()
    converting_to = (request.form['converting_to']).upper()
    c= CurrencyCodes()
    try:
         c.get_symbol(converting_from)
    except KeyError:
        message = "{converting_from} is not a valid currency code!"
    
    try:
         c.get_symbol(converting_to)
    except KeyError:
        message = "{converting_to} is not a valid currency code!"

return render_template('base.html',message=message)

def check_valid_number():
    amount = request.form['amount']
    if amount.isnumeric() == True:
        amount= float(amount)
        return amount
    else:
        message = "Not a valid amount."

return render_template('base.html',message=message)
```

Comment: I shouldn't need to enter message as a parameter if I'm using the built in flash() function though correct?

Comment: Also, I am using render_template in my app.py, but the code I showed is from my errors_check.py. After I run those checks I render the base template, but my flash messages don't appear